# How would one create an SSRS datasource to quickbooks?

Tags: ssrs

My team is stuck. We are attempting to create reporting in SSRS to connect to quick books. We were successful in creating DAO connections in ms access, however we want to have reporting in SSRS and not ms access.

Comment: Have you tried to set something up in SSIS or SQL Server Data tools or whatever the current name is, import the data into SQL and then use SSRS to run reports against the data locally?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set up an ADO.Net DataSource in SSRS:

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/quickbooks-ado-ssrs-server.rst

Comment: Please provide the core of the answer at least as text here, and not jus with a link.